# How to get data from VirtualTable using QTP?

Tags: listview, qtp

How can I get data from `VirtualTable` using QTP?

`VirtualTable` is the Virtual Object I have created in QTP.
I have created `virtualTable` because the QTP is identifying listview as `winObject` only.